# How do I develop an OAuth Authorization page which a user can interact with but not the application being authorized?

Tags: mobile, oauth, authorization

How do I develop an OAuth Authorization page which a user can interact with but not the application being authorized?

I'm developing an API set and want to allow mobile apps to interact with the API, provided that they're authorized to do so on behalf of the user.

Once I've authenticated the user, how do I ensure that the user has clicked the OK button, rather than the application itself?

Regards,
Yusuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the need to enter any type of verification code such as reentering a password or typing in a Captcha, before sending the access token.